# Usage view and model in methods

Tags: java, swing, view

Is there any universal law to use `viewIndex` or `modelIndex` in methods?

For example in `JTable.getValueAt()` method, We should send a view index or a model index?

I use sorting/filtering capabilities in my table.

Occasionally is use `viewIndex` and some times use `modelIndex` !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general rule, you would use the view value for accessing the row. This will work when using filtering and sorting.

The column can be a little more complicated depending on your requirement. If you want the data of the selected cell, then use the view. Other times you want to use the model value to access a column.

For example, you know that column 0 of the model always contains an "ID" for data in a database. So maybe you have logic that when a user clicks on a row you need to go to the database for more information. So you would use the view row and the model column, because it is possible that the user could have reorder the TableColumns of the view, so you can't be certain that column 0, represent the "ID" anymore.